# How to select the last 5 list items when targetting a specific unordered list using jQuery AJAX?

Tags: ajax, jquery

I haven't done much jQuery AJAX stuff and just started  to learn the load function which works absolutely amazing for what I needed to... but my question is now more specific on how I could possibly selected only the last 5 records/list items when targeting a specific list items...

For example;

Page name: targeted.html

```
  <div id="targeted_div">
  <ul>
  <li>Want to select this list item</li>
  <li>Want to select this list item</li>
  <li>Want to select this list item</li>
  <li>Want to select this list item</li>
  <li>Want to select this list item</li>
  <li>Do NOT want this list item</li>
  <li>Do NOT want this list item</li>
  <li>Do NOT want this list item</li>
  <li>Do NOT want this list item</li>
  <li>Do NOT want this list item</li>
  <li>Do NOT want this list item</li>
  <li>Do NOT want this list item</li>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

Page name: new.html

```
<div id="new_div">
</div>
```

I usually select them the entire unordered list like;

```
<script>
$('#new_div').load('/targeted.html #targeted_div');
</script>
```

So how could this be done, thanks in advance :)
Also is it possible to select the last 5 record from bottom to top...
Cheers

Comment: Can you add a class to the li elements that you want to select?Soemthing like this:

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`:lt()`-selector](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/)

```
$('<ul/>')
 .appendTo($('#new_div').empty())
   .load('/targeted.html #targeted_div li:lt(5)');
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the last 5 elements in the `targeted.html` file:

```
<div id="targeted_div">
  <ul>
    <li class='selectMe'>Want to select this list item</li>
    <li class='selectMe'>Want to select this list item</li>
    <li class='selectMe'>Want to select this list item</li>
    <li class='selectMe'>Want to select this list item</li>
    <li class='selectMe'>Want to select this list item</li>
    <li>Do NOT want this list item</li>
    <li>Do NOT want this list item</li>
    <li>Do NOT want this list item</li>
    <li>Do NOT want this list item</li>
    <li>Do NOT want this list item</li>
    <li>Do NOT want this list item</li>
    <li>Do NOT want this list item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Then, in `new.html` run:

```
<script>
   //get only $('.selectMe') elements from targeted.html contents
   var loadedCode = $.load('/targeted.html .selectMe');

   //construct new code
   var newCode = '<ul>'+loadedCode+'</ul>';

   //insert new code into #newDiv
   $('#newDiv').html(newCode);

   //reorder <li> elements
   var ul = $("ul");
   var li = ul.children("li");
   li.detach().sort();
   ul.append(li);
</script>
```